# what happen to the execution stack if a function does not return?

Tags: c, operating-system

In C, what will happens to a thread's execution stack if a function does not return?

```
void funcB() __attribute__ ((noreturn));

int funcA (...)
{
   // do stuff
   funcB();
   // do more stuff
}
```

An example of this situation is, says, funcA is the kernel function that creates a new thread and funcB is kernel code that switches the new thread to user mode and let it run.

Thank you.

Comment: The events described in the question (and the question itself) aren't clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Functions that don't return are either termination functions, in which case the entire process is about to be cleaned up, or things like `exec`, which also replace the entire program image. The upshot is that we don't need the stack anymore.

Comment: Yes, what do you expect to happen? exit(0) also never returns, the stack used till that point stays reserved till the program exits...

Comment: A function that calls longjmp() also will never return, but the longjmp() will move the stack pointer to where it was at the time of its originating setjmp(). Edit: Assuming the longjmp target was not established within this function.

Comment: The code marked `// do more stuff` is never going to execute, unless `funcB` fails for some reason. Since you're talking about kernel code, `funcB` presumably causes the system call to finish and return to user mode. This is done by the equivalent of a longjmp(), as mah described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html

As it says in the section about `noreturn`:

> Do not assume that registers saved by the calling function are restored before calling the noreturn function.

I assume this means that there is no guarantee that, for example, the stack pointer (or other stack frame elements) will be restored after the `noreturn` function finishes.